# How to saturare Point Cloud Material in Three.js

Tags: three.js, alphablending, blending, point-clouds

I've a point cloud object in Three.js with thousands of 2d geo location points. They are laying on the same z plane.

Currently, with using normal blending with semitransparent points,  I can achieve the first result of the image below, blending the colors of the overlapping points to achieve an alpha value of 1.

I'm interested to achieve the saturation of the second image where overlapping points saturate to white. Is it possible using only blending? or I need something else like Effect Composer?

Thanks

[image]